# Movie where main guy has a scar on his hand from getting shot by a bullet

Tags: story-identification, movie

Does anyone know a movie where the main guy and his (ex??)girlfriend both have scars on their hands from a gunshot?

I watched this movie about 12 years ago at the movie theatres and I've been trying to find it again. I don't remember much from it though, just that there was a scene at the beginning where there was some type of alien girl with 3 boobs and there were flying cars.

Comment: Sounds like the movie with Arnold Schwarzenegger... Total Recall?

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104794/movie-with-people-on-mars-mars-atmosphere-has-a-problem-and-guy-saves-them-all (about the 1990 original)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the [2012 remake of *Total Recall*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Recall_(2012_film)).

> Colony worker Douglas Quaid has been having unsettling dreams of being a secret agent partnered with an unnamed woman. Tired of his factory job building police robots with his friend Harry, he visits Rekall, a company that implants artificial memories. He decides on the fantasy of being a secret agent. During exploratory preparations by technician McClane, they discover that Quaid already has real memories of being a spy. As McClane starts to question Quaid about the memories, a squad of UFB police arrive, killing the Rekall staff in an attempt to arrest Quaid. Strange instincts kick in as Quaid defends himself, killing the entire squad. Upon returning home, Quaid relays the incident to his wife Lori, who attempts to kill him but fails. She reveals that she is a UFB intelligence agent and they have only been married for six weeks, not seven years as he believed. After Quaid escapes, he receives a phone call from Charles Hammond, a former colleague of his who directs him to a safe-deposit box. Inside it Quaid finds a message from himself with the address of an apartment in UFB.

....

> Melina revealed that she was Hauser's lover before he was captured, comparing ***their matching scars from a time they were shot while holding hands in Quaid's "dream"***.

Indeed, [there is a three-breasted woman](https://twincitiesgeek.com/2015/04/throwback-thursday-dystopian-dick-total-recall/), as per the original film.

(Hidden below spoiler for saucy image with censor bar covering naughty bits, probably NSFW at most places)

> [image: Three-breasted woman with censor bar]